# Как передать массив в следующий promise js

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

Хотелось бы передать в промис (тот что после комментария в коде) айди пользователя, помимо переменной lenta, сейчас передается только lenta:

```
'use strict';
var InstagramPrivateAPI = {};

InstagramPrivateAPI = {};
InstagramPrivateAPI.V1 = require(__dirname + '/client/v1');
InstagramPrivateAPI.Helpers = require(__dirname + '/helpers');
var acc = require(__dirname + "/client/v1/account");
var med = require(__dirname + "/client/v1/media")

var Promise = require('../bluebird');
var _ = require('../lodash/');

module.exports = InstagramPrivateAPI;

var Client = require('instagram-private-api').V1;
var device = new Client.Device('maksgmn');
var storage = new Client.CookieFileStorage(__dirname + '/cookies/maksgmn.json');

acc.searchForUser(session, 'kaigreene')
    .then(function(profile) {
        return profile.id
    })
    .then(function(someId) {
        var feed = new Client.Feed.UserMedia(session, someId);
        var lenta = Promise.mapSeries(_.range(0, 1), function() {
            return feed.get();
        })
        return lenta
    })
    //вот промис в который нужно передать lenta и айди пользователя
    .then(function(results) {
        // result should be Media[][]
        var media = _.flatten(results);
        var urls = _.map(media, function(medium) {
            return medium.params.imageVersions2.candidates[0].url
        });
        console.log(urls)
    })
```

Кстати вот содержимое urls (массив ссылок на изображения, после обработки 
lenta):

```
[ 'https://scontent-arn2-1.cdninstagram.com/vp/6af16d285248021beb138878d39300f5/5C7ABDF2/t51.2885-15/e35/44564146_322592125137172_4748922672367052265_n.jpg?ig_cache_key=MTkxNTA2MzY3NjkyMDg3NzI4NQ%3D%3D.2',
  'https://scontent-arn2-1.cdninstagram.com/vp/fafb1cbedf2f2ee526b53bbbe19242e0/5BF37B8A/t51.2885-15/e15/p640x640/43536314_2236965789913961_7161939884150660296_n.jpg',
  'https://scontent-arn2-1.cdninstagram.com/vp/40aa382750e5e94a6e66d57c61381280/5C7E3B85/t51.2885-15/e35/44183920_263573101019253_2196926879861470922_n.jpg?ig_cache_key=MTkxNDI0NTA3MjY5NjQ0Mzg2MQ%3D%3D.2',
  'https://scontent-arn2-1.cdninstagram.com/vp/0f494a3130df8f5e9020adba2aaeaaa1/5C8D533C/t51.2885-15/e35/44453843_206191696937914_2654101859534502211_n.jpg?ig_cache_key=MTkxNDA4NDAwNzQ1NTExMjY3Mw%3D%3D.2',
  'https://scontent-arn2-1.cdninstagram.com/vp/891e76d89e68cef102ca82891bd79500/5C7D169D/t51.2885-15/e35/45513332_314414985821365_5157081956783129672_n.jpg?ig_cache_key=MTkxNDAxOTA3MjAzNzQ2OTc0OA%3D%3D.2',
  'https://scontent-arn2-1.cdninstagram.com/vp/8630ce604e8fc13c4b0f8dea529066c3/5BF360C2/t51.2885-15/e15/44277878_2176945342563453_2262613550408503718_n.jpg',
  'https://scontent-arn2-1.cdninstagram.com/vp/10c7c4f145e8c749d9865b9042b594ba/5C6D275A/t51.2885-15/e35/44589483_282353665729077_4185404619021489633_n.jpg?ig_cache_key=MTkxMzQ2NTEyMjA3MDQ3Mjk2NA%3D%3D.2',
  'https://scontent-arn2-1.cdninstagram.com/vp/c99a00b3d36a5013736920475b98cadb/5C8D2738/t51.2885-15/e35/44850363_1912754462367214_2546260771931931006_n.jpg?ig_cache_key=MTkxMzMwMzc3ODc4ODY5NDI0Mg%3D%3D.2',
  'https://scontent-arn2-1.cdninstagram.com/vp/b850a45fe4cc20a93da64857aee9575c/5C8D1984/t51.2885-15/e35/44634212_1869528946493492_7969207514966425740_n.jpg?ig_cache_key=MTkxMjc0MTYxMDc4NzgwOTAzNQ%3D%3D.2',
  'https://scontent-arn2-1.cdninstagram.com/vp/28e6be91c8fc996dfc47b8ea3e9781d6/5BF3CAE9/t51.2885-15/e15/43398735_115170416088701_3256913169852741968_n.jpg',
  'https://scontent-arn2-1.cdninstagram.com/vp/60e627e88aeef3ded3466d1e8a80f6fd/5BF3E157/t51.2885-15/e15/43258810_358264328256668_5269209695486174863_n.jpg',
  'https://scontent-arn2-1.cdninstagram.com/vp/85487f3fb5b805ce3fc63b40a9d5e121/5BF35B86/t51.2885-15/e15/s640x640/43504006_685794225133434_1066643086450380052_n.jpg' ]
```

Пробовал сделать следующим образом:

```
'use strict';
    var InstagramPrivateAPI = {};

    InstagramPrivateAPI = {};
    InstagramPrivateAPI.V1 = require(__dirname + '/client/v1');
    InstagramPrivateAPI.Helpers = require(__dirname + '/helpers');
    var acc = require(__dirname + "/client/v1/account");
    var med = require(__dirname + "/client/v1/media")

    var Promise = require('../bluebird');
    var _ = require('../lodash/');

    module.exports = InstagramPrivateAPI;

    var Client = require('instagram-private-api').V1;
    var device = new Client.Device('maksgmn');
    var storage = new Client.CookieFileStorage(__dirname + '/cookies/maksgmn.json');

    acc.searchForUser(session, 'kaigreene')
        .then(function(profile) {
            return profile.id
        })
        .then(function(someId) {
            var feed = new Client.Feed.UserMedia(session, someId);
            var lenta = Promise.mapSeries(_.range(0, 1), function() {
                return feed.get();
            })
            return {id : someId, fd : lenta}
        })
        //затем тут уже передаем results.fd
        .then(function(results) {
            // result should be Media[][]
            var media = _.flatten(results.fd);
            var urls = _.map(media, function(medium) {
                return medium.params.imageVersions2.candidates[0].url
            });
            console.log(urls)
        })
```

Но в итоге получаю пустой массив при выводе console.log(urls)

Подскажите, как можно сделать, чтобы нормально передевалось в следующий промис айди пользователя и вот эта переменная lenta

Answer (score 1):

`lenta` в данном случае - тоже `Promise`, и чтобы передать его значение, нужно дождаться его окончания.

Например можно использовать [`Promise.all`](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.all.html)

```
return Promise.all([someId,lenta])
```

Тогда в следующем `then`, параметром будет массив с двумя элементами: 0 элемент - someId, 1 элемент - значение `lenta`

Получить их можно с помощью деструктуризации:

```
.then(function([someId, lenta]){
    var media = _.flatten(lenta);
    ...
})
```